# Firefox specific media queries

Tags: firefox, responsive-design, media-queries

This is probably a VERY simple question, but I am having a hard time! I have an external CSS file that is working fine and is responsive. As to be expected, the positioning of a few elements is a little "off" when viewed in Firefox. I wanted to write a media query for when the page is viewed in Firefox, and adjust the margins, etc. of a specific element. I thought you could use the prefix:

```
@-moz-document url-prefix()
```

as a media query, but that didn't do anything.

How do you write a media query for when the page is viewed in Firefox and Safari?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use the selector you mentioned, e.g.:

```
@-moz-document url-prefix() {
  h1, p{
    color:pink;
  }
}
```

See this live: http://codepen.io/panchroma/pen/gpXdRj

More about Firefox vendor selectors: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Mozilla_Extensions#font-family

More browser selectors and hacks: http://browserhacks.com

FWIW, have you double-checked that your FireFox layout issues aren't related to browser default settings and that they couldn't be solved by using a different CSS reset? I've had success in the past with [normalize.css](http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/)

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks very much, David! That's what I had, and it wasn't working, but I'll try again. The thing that needs to change in Firefox is just the percentage of a margin-- I can't imagine that would be related to a browser default setting issue, could it? I'm including normalize.css in all my pages.

Comment: It worked this time!! I must have had something wrong the first time. Thank you so so so so much!!!!!! :)

Answer (score 5):

This query only affect to mozilla navigator:

```
@media all and (min--moz-device-pixel-ratio:0) and (max-width: 680px){...}
```

And this is only for IE:

```
@media screen and (-ms-high-contrast:active), (-ms-high-contrast:none) and (max-width: 680px){...}
```

More information here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/CSS/Media_queries

Best wishes!!